# Any performance improvements using PLinq in DomainService query operations

Tags: .net, silverlight, performance, wcf-ria-services, plinq

Can i expect any performance improvements if i use the .AsParallel() extension in the query operations of my domain service. The DomainService uses a Repository (EntityFramework) to query data and to build up ViewModels for the client that are returned by the query operations.

Here´s a simple query operation in my DomainService:

```
[Query]
public IQueryable<ProductViewModel> GetProductSet() {
  var products = from product in _productRepository.Query()
                 select product;

  return (from product in products.ToList() 
          select new ProductViewModel() { Product = product}).AsQueryable();
}
```

If i can speed up things using PLinq, where should i add the .AsParallel() call?

Here

```
_productRepository.Query().AsParallel();
```

There

```
products.AsParallel().ToList()
```

or there

```
product.ToList().AsParallel()
```

Comment: why are you materialising the list and then passing back as IQueryable?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Cause only parameterless or object initializers are allowed in LinqToEntities. So i need to materialize them to call my ctor. Maybe i change it to object initializer.